# Prove $P(A)\cap P(B) = \{\emptyset\}\implies A \cap B = \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I prove $P(A)\cap P(B) = \{\emptyset\}\implies A \cap B = \emptyset$. I can't seem to find an effective way.

Comment: Hint: Let $A\cap B=C$.  Prove that $P(A)\cap P(B)=P(C)$.  Using the contrapositive, if $C\not=\emptyset$, $P(C)\not=\{\emptyset\}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Doing the contrapositive:

Suppose that $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$. Let $x\in A\cap B$. Then $\{x\}\subset A$ and $\{x\}\subset B$ implying that $\{x\}\in P(A)\cap P(B)$.

Comment: This is rather more than a hint. +1 anyway.

Comment: Thank you! Is it valid then to state as the final justification that because x is an element of A $\cup$ B then {x} has to be an element of P(A) $\cup$ P(B) , thus implying that P(A) $\cup$ P(B) can't be {$\emptyset$} since it does not include {x}? I can't believe i'm having such a hard time with such a simple exercise...

Comment: @Jean Beaucamp Why union? Your question is about intersection?

Comment: @Jean Beaucamp Anyway, if $\{x\}\subset A$ then it means that $\{x\}\in P(A)$. So, in the end, the set $P(A)\cap P(B)$ contains $\emptyset$ and $\{x\}$

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the symbol in the comment. It's intersection.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\,A \cap B \subseteq A\,$ thus $A \cap B \in P(A)\,$, and similarly $\,A \cap B \in P(B)\,$, so $\,A \cap B \in P(A) \cap P(B)$.